# Call a method with dynamic class name in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.1

How can we call class functions with a dynamic class name?

Assume the following example where I have two class with methods with same signature

```
class Foo{
   class func doSomething()

}

class Foobar {
   class func doSomething()
}

class ActualWork{
   //call following method with a variable type so that it accepts dynamic class  name
   func callDynamicClassMethod(x: dynamicClass)
    x.doSomething() 
  }
```

How can this be implemented so that x accepts values at run time

Edit: Sorry, I missed to mention that I was looking for any other ways other than protocol oriented approach. This is more of an exploratory question to explore if there is a more direct approach/pods/libraries to achieve this.

Comment: I would try to add a protocol to the Foo and Foobar with doSomething(). Then make a genericType the requires that protocol - then use the genericType as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I liked this question, because it made me to think a lit'bit outside of the box.

I'll answer it, by dividing it into a few parts.

**First**

> call class functions

Class function is basically a [Type methods](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html), which can be achieved using the `static` word inside the `class` context.

Taking that into account, you can get a simple solution, using [protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) and passing the class reference (conforming to that protocol) like this:

```
protocol Aaa{
   static func doSomething();
}
class Foo : Aaa{
  static func doSomething() {
    print("Foo doing something");
  }
}
class FooBar : Aaa{
  static func doSomething() {
    print("FooBar doing something");
  }
}

class ActualWork{

  //Using class (static) method
  func callDynamicClassMethod <T: Aaa> (x: T.Type) {
    x.doSomething();
  }
}


//This is how you can use it
func usage(){
    let aw = ActualWork();

    aw.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.self);
    aw.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.self);
}
```

**Second**

In case you don't really need the method on the class context, you may consider using instance methods. In that case the solution would be even simpler, like this:

```
protocol Bbb{
  func doSomething();
}
class Bar : Bbb{
  func doSomething() {
    print("Bar instance doing something");
  }
}
class BarBar : Bbb{
  func doSomething() {
    print("BarBar instance doing something");
  }
}
class ActualWork{
  //Using instance (non-static) method
  func callDynamicInstanceMethod <T: Bbb> (x: T){
    x.doSomething();
  }
}
//This is how you can use it
func usage(){
   let aw = ActualWork();
    aw.callDynamicInstanceMethod(x: Bar());
    aw.callDynamicInstanceMethod(x: BarBar());
}
```

**Third**

If you need to use the `class func` syntax, as OP originally did:

> class func doSomething()

You CANNOT simply use a protocol. Because protocol is not a class...
So compiler won't allow it.

[image: Cannot declare class function inside protocol]

But it's still possible, you can achieve that by using
[Selector](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH48) with [NSObject.perform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-perform) method

like this:

```
class ActualWork : NSObject{

    func callDynamicClassMethod<T: NSObject>(x: T.Type, methodName: String){
        x.perform(Selector(methodName));
    }

}

class Ccc : NSObject{
    @objc class func doSomething(){
        print("Ccc class Doing something ");
    }

}

class Ddd : NSObject{
    @objc class func doSomething(){
        print("Ccc class Doing something ");
    }

    @objc class func doOther(){
        print("Ccc class Doing something ");
    }
}

//This is how you can use it
func usage() {
    let aw = ActualWork();

    aw.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Ccc.self, methodName: "doSomething");
    aw.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Ddd.self, methodName: "doSomething");
    aw.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Ddd.self, methodName: "doOther");

}
```

Comment: I think selectors is the only way to go if one wants to avoid protocols.

Answer (score 7):

Generics and Protocol oriented programming will do the job:

```
protocol Doable {

    static func doSomething()
}

class Foo: Doable {

    static func doSomething() {
        debugPrint("Foo")
    }
}

class Foobar: Doable {

    static func doSomething() {
        debugPrint("Foobar")
    }
}

class ActualWork {

    func callDynamicClassMethod<T: Doable>(x: T.Type) {
        x.doSomething()
    }
}

let work = ActualWork()

work.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.self)
work.callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foobar.self)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this with help of Protocol

```
 protocol common {
   static func doSomething()
}


class Foo : common{
   static  func doSomething() {
        print("Foo")
    }
}

class Foobar : common {
   static func doSomething() {
        print("Foobar")
    }
}


class ActualWork{
    //call following method with a variable type so that it accepts dynamic class  name
    func callDynamicClassMethod(x: common.Type) {
            x.doSomething()
    }
}

let fooObj : common = Foo()
let Foobarobj : common = Foobar()

let workObk = ActualWork()
workObk.callDynamicClassMethod(x:Foo.self)
workObk.callDynamicClassMethod(x:Foobar.self)
```

Comment: Question is about class functions

Answer (score 3):

I think, there are three solutions. I shared an sample below.

1. Use "protocol" that has "doSomething()" function requirements.
2. Create a function which gets function definition as a parameter.
3. Use reflection. you can use [EVReflection](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) that is good Api for reflection.

sample code:

```swift
protocol FooProtocol {
    static func doSomething()
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {
    class func doSomething() {
        print("Foo:doSomething")
    }
}

class Foobar: FooProtocol {
    class func doSomething() {
        print("Foobar:doSomething")
    }
}

class ActualWork {
    func callDynamicClassMethod<T: FooProtocol>(x: T.Type) {
        x.doSomething()
    }

    func callDynamicClassMethod(x: @autoclosure () -> Void) {
        x()
    }

    func callDynamicClassMethod(x: () -> Void) {
        x()
    }
}

ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.self)
ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foobar.self)
print("\n")
ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.doSomething())
ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foobar.doSomething())
print("\n")
ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foo.doSomething)
ActualWork().callDynamicClassMethod(x: Foobar.doSomething)
```

Comment: Good solutions 

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are searching for [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and this is harder to achieve in a statically typed language (with some exceptions, listed in the linked Wikipedia page).

This is because dynamically calling a method requires knowledge about the layout of the target object, thus either inheritance of the class declaring the method, or conformance to a protocol that requires that method.

Starting with Swift 4.2, and the introduction of [dynamic member lookup](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0195-dynamic-member-lookup.md), there is another approach to solve your problem, however it also involves some ceremony:

```swift
// This needs to be used as base of all classes that you want to pass
// as arguments 
@dynamicMemberLookup
class BaseDynamicClass {
    subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () -> Void {
        return { /* empty closure do nothing */ }
    }
}

// subclasses can choose to respond to member queries any way they like
class Foo: BaseDynamicClass {
    override subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () -> Void {
        if member == "doSomething" { return doSomething }
        return super[dynamicMember: member]
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Dynamic from Foo")
    }

}

class Bar: BaseDynamicClass {
    override subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> () -> Void {
        if member == "doSomething" { return doSomething }
        return super[dynamicMember: member]
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("Dynamic from Bar")
    }
}

func test(receiver: BaseDynamicClass) {
    receiver.doSomething()
}

test(receiver: Bar()) // Dynamic from Bar
```

To conclude, in the current Swift version there is no way to have both the argument and the method dynamic, some common ground needs to be set.